# Can any one help id this bug or at least tell me if it could be biting my kids

Tags: species-identification, species

We live on the gold coast in australia. We started looking into what these bugs were after my son became covered in severe bites. Hes always reacted a little bit to bites but this was intense.  The initial bite looked somewhat like a raised welt which he has scratched at but now over a week later hes saying they are still itchy and even with bandaging and covering the areas hes still getting more bites.  I have attached a photo of the bugs that are around at the moment but also some of the bites. we get alot of mosquitos and midgies (sand flies) but hes never reacted to those bites like this. We have recently had a flood in the area so everything is still wet. Its change of season so its cooling down.  Any help would be amazing in helping treat our son but also hopefully prevent further issues[image][image]

Comment: Questions seeking medical advice are not allowed here. You should rewrite your question so that it just about identifying the insect.

Comment: it looks like a biting midge to me.

Comment: It is certainly a Diptera. How big is it? Biting midges are usually very small, 1-3mm, this one looks bigger.